# libgdx render blank texture performance

Tags: performance, opengl, opengl-es, libgdx

If I render a big texture 1024x1024 but almost the texture is transparent, only about 40% of the texture have data (not transparent). Does it more slower than render a texture with less transparent part?

I have this question because when render a animation, it is more easy to set the pivot of sprite in the image itself, so when I render i only need to draw each sprite at the center of my object's position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more performant, because your image will be smaller. But I doubt it will make a noticeable difference. So, the way you are doing it right now is good, thats how I do it.